# Why "points.clear" and "points.add" (points is a list of Offset) do not work the same in 10 trial in CustomPaint in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, addition, custom-painter

It works for some trials and then doesn't work for some trials and then works again (without any particular pattern). I mean for example it corrects the line and draw a perfect one for 3-4 times with only the first and last point and then for one time it leaves the line that the user drew. It seems that the `points.clear` or `points.add` sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. I know it sounds silly but I can not explain it in a logical way. I would be really thankful if someone could look at the code and tell me what's going on.

here is my GestureDetector:

```
body: GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (DragDownDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            points.clear();
          });
        },
        onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
          //when the user touch the screen and move
          setState(() {
            RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject(); //finds the scaffold
            Offset point = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
            point = point.translate(0.0, -(AppBar().preferredSize.height + 30));

            points = List.from(points)
              ..add(point); //add the points when user drag in screen
            firstPoint = points.first; //storing the first point for drawing the line
          });
        },
        onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            if (mode == "Line") {
              Offset lastPoint = points.last; //storing the last point for drawing the line
              points.clear();
              points.add(firstPoint);
              points.add(lastPoint);
              points.add(null);
            } 
          });
        },
        child: sketchArea,
      ),
```

and here is my CustomPainter class:

```
class Sketcher2 extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> points;
  Sketcher2(this.points);

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Sketcher2 oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.points != points;
  }

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black //seting the color of the drawing
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round //the shape of a single dot (single touch)
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0; // the width of a single dot (single touch)

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with the `shouldRepaint` of your `Sketcher2`:

```dart
@override
bool shouldRepaint(Sketcher2 oldDelegate) {
  return oldDelegate.points != points;
}
```

The `!=` operator compares the objects. It will return true if and only if `oldDelegate.points` and `points` are not the same object.

In fact, I'm quite surprised it ever works. I tried your source code and it never works on my side.

### 1. Quick Solution

In `onPanEnd`, instead of clearing the points, reinitialize the list to a new `[]`:

```dart
onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    if (mode == "Line") {
      Offset lastPoint = points.last;
      points = []; // instead of points.clear();
      points.add(firstPoint);
      points.add(lastPoint);
      points.add(null);
    } else if (mode == "FreeDraw") {
      points.add(null);
    }
  });
},
```

BTW, you did it properly in `onPanUpdate` by using a copy of the List with `points = List.from(points)..add(point);`.

### 2. Further simplifications

You could simplify your GestureDetector quite a bit.

- You `firstPoint` is `points.first`, no need to keep a separate variable for that;
- Same for your `lastPoints`;
- The `details` of `onPanUpdate` already give you the `localPosition`;
- Why do you add `null` at the end of the `points`?

Your `Page` becomes:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Offset> points = <Offset>[];
  String mode = 'Line';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (DragDownDetails details) => setState(() => points = []),
        onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) =>
            setState(() => points = [...points, details.localPosition]),
        onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => setState(() {
          if (mode == "Line") points = [points.first, points.last];
        }),
        child: SketchArea(points: points),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I changed the points.add(firstPoint) to points = List.from(points)..add(firstPoint) and the other one as well and my problem solved. But I definitely look into your other advice and make my code better.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed this part:

```
points.add(firstPoint);
points.add(lastPoint);
```

to

```
points = List.from(points)..add(firstPoint);
points = List.from(points)..add(lastPoint);
```

and my problem solved.